# Splitting single raster within multiple polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, clip

I have a raster ('slope') which content only one attribute in the table. On the other hand I have a feature which content several polygons (catchments) in the attributes table. I would like to obtain the area or count of the 'slope' for each catchments.

Is there any faster way to do it without separating the catchments and masking the rasters one by one?

Answer (score 1):

This type of analysis is typically achieved using [Zonal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics/009z000000w7000000/) or [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/).  More details on Zonal Statistics are available [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/How_Zonal_Statistics_works/009z000000wt000000/).

Alternatively, [Tabulate Area](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Tabulate_Area/009z000000w2000000/) calculates cross-tabulated areas between two datasets and outputs a table.